# Django views calls functions several times

Tags: python, django

I am creating a browser-based RPG where fighting mechanics are built into a model called "Battle". It performs actions on Hero, Monster and Item models according to some formulas. Each action adds a message to a "battle log". A player can issue a fight against another player or NPC in a form. When the form is submitted, it calls the same view, the Battle object is created, the characters are drafted and the game mechanics are run.

For some reason, old "Battle" objects are still "selected" between runs of these views, as long as it's in the same web session. So even though I create a new object, the old battle log gets carried over to this new object. 
What am I doing wrong here?

**Updated with more context**

The fightlog field in the first object is correct.
The fightlog field in the second object is the the first objects data PLUS the new data.
The third fightlog is the first plus second plus third, etc.

views.py

```
def battle_log(request):

    if request.session["last_battle"]:
        pk = request.session["last_battle"]
        b = Battletest.objects.get(pk=pk)
        battle_log = b.fightlog

        request.session["last_battle"] = ""
        context = { 'battle_log' : battle_log, }

        return render(request, 'battle.html', context)

    else:
        return redirect('/game/monster')

def fight_select_monster(request):
    form = SelectCharacter()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = SelectCharacter(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            b = Battletest.objects.create()
            b.draft(request.POST.get("character"))
            b.start_fight()
            b.round()
            b.eof()
            b.save()

            request.session["last_battle"] =  b.pk
            return redirect('/game/fight/')

    context = { 'form': form }
    request.session["last_battle"] = ""
    return render(request, 'fight.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Battletest(models.Model):
    messages = []
    fightlog = models.TextField()
    opponent = ""

    def draft(self, opponent):
        CHARACTERS= (
            (0, 'Confident Hacker'),
            (1, 'Confused Coder'),
        )
        self.opponent = CHARACTERS[int(opponent)][1]

    def start_fight(self):
        self.messages.append([0, "You joined the battle."])
        self.messages.append([0, self.opponent + "has appeared"])

    def round(self):
        # have character objects do stuff to eachother until
        # some edge case is met.
        self.messages.append([1, "You smack " + self.opponent + " in the face"])
        self.messages.append([1, self.opponent + " decides to leave this stupid fight"])

    def eof(self):
        self.messages.append([2, "The fight is over and noone wins"])
        self.fightlog = self.messages
```

forms.py

```
class SelectCharacter(forms.Form):

    CONFIDENTHACKER = 0
    CONFUSEDCODER = 1
    CHARACTERS= (
        (CONFIDENTHACKER, 'Confident Hacker'),
        (CONFUSEDCODER, 'Confused Coder'),
    )
    character = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHARACTERS)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and eventually edit your question - actually, just building a proper [mcve] might be enough to find out and olve the issue by yourself ;-)

Comment: Also - mostly unrelated but -, in your `fight_select_monster` view, you want to move the `context = { 'form': form }` statement at the end of the function, just before the `return` statement - else you'll never get the errors for invalid forms.

Comment: And finally, by all means, [use named urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) - don't harcode them.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers! I skimmed through the links you provided and rewrote the functions to make it clearer for an outsider, but still, I am not able to identify the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your issue is here:

```
class Battletest(models.Model):
    messages = []
    opponent = ""
```

This defines `messages` and `opponent` as *class* attributes 
 - attributes that belong to the class object itself and as such are shared between all instances of the class, making them, practically, global variables (since class objects are singletons).

What you want here is to make `messages` an instance attribute by defining int in the initializer (that's what it's for):

```
class Battletest(models.Model):
     fightlog = models.TextField()

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # let Model do it's own stuff !!!
         super(Battletest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

         # and add our ones:
         self.messages = []
         self.opponent = None
```

As a side note: such mistakes are often the sign someone kind of "jumped in" Django without learning Python's basics first and wrongly assumes that because Django models use class attribute to define db fields, Python's class syntax is the same as Java or PHP where you define attributes at the class top-level. But [that's not how Python works](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) and I very strongly suggest that at this point you stop everything and do the whole official Python tutorial - it will saves you a **lot** of time and pain, really.

*As a second side note: in the context of server side web app, you want to avoid **any** kind of (mutable) global state in your code. Every bit of mutable global state should live in some databaseyour models, sessions, whatever as long as it's external to your code AND can be shared amongst many processes - because in a typical production setup, your app WILL be served by many distinct processes (yes, even if you have one single HTTP front server, it will typically manage a pool of django processes, and requests will arbitrarily dispatched to any of those processes).*

Now, you have another issue here:

```
def eof(self):
    # ...
    self.fightlog = self.messages
```

You defined `fightlog` as a text field, but you're assigning a list of lists to it. What get saved will be a textual representation of the list, which is not very usable.

Theoretically, what you have here is a one to many relationship (a Battletest has many Message), so the proper relational design would be to use a distinct `Message` model with a `ForeignKey` on `Battletest` - [as shown in the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models) (you did the tutorial, did you ?).

Now if you really insist on denormalizing this, the best (less worse at least) solution is to serialize `messages` to `json` at `save()` time and unserialize it back to Python in the initializer. This can be done manually:

```
import json

class Battletest(models.Model):
     fightlog = models.TextField()

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # let Model do it's own stuff !!!
         super(Battletest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

         # and add our ones:
         if self.fightlog:
             self.messages = json.loads(self.fightlog)
         else:
             self.messages = []
         self.opponent = None

    # ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fightlog = json.dumps(self.messages)
        super(Battletest, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

or using a `JSONField` (that will more or less automagically take care of this) if your RDBMS support it. Googling for "django JSONField" should provide some hints...

Oh and yes... you have duplicated code here:

```
class Battletest(models.Model):

    # ...

    def draft(self, opponent):
        CHARACTERS= (
            (0, 'Confident Hacker'),
            (1, 'Confused Coder'),
        )
        self.opponent = CHARACTERS[int(opponent)][1]
```

and here:

```
class SelectCharacter(forms.Form):

    CONFIDENTHACKER = 0
    CONFUSEDCODER = 1
    CHARACTERS= (
        (CONFIDENTHACKER, 'Confident Hacker'),
        (CONFUSEDCODER, 'Confused Coder'),
    )
    character = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHARACTERS)
```

You want to factor this out so you have one single point of truth:

```
class Battletest(models.Model):

        CONFIDENTHACKER = 0
        CONFUSEDCODER = 1
        CHARACTERS= [
            (CONFIDENTHACKER, 'Confident Hacker'),
            (CONFUSEDCODER, 'Confused Coder'),
        ]


    def draft(self, opponent):
        self.opponent = self.CHARACTERS[int(opponent)][1]
```

and in your forms.py:

```
from . models import Battletest

class SelectCharacter(forms.Form):
    character = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Battltest.CHARACTERS)
```

Comment: Great and very humble thanks! Both for the general remarks on better practice and the steps and pointers towards solving my issues. I've gone way ahead of myself into this venture. I have previously completed tutorials mentioned, but have not spent enough time repeating the basics. Back to the school bench.